# File uploading in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application [asp.net], when i am trying to upload a .doc file which is having 6 mb size, when i click ok button it is giving one empty tab in browser, where as when i upload small size .doc it is uploading, why it  is like this, can you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the default size allowed in IIS the `maxAllowedContentLength`.

You can change this in your web.config as well. An example:

```
<system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"/>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: ya Mr. Jeremy Child i will check and get back you

Comment: in web.config the code you give is in kb, whta is that means '524288000'

Comment: Mr. Jeremy Child it is giving same ting empty borwoser

Comment: Interesting. Are you using the development IIS(from debug in visual studio) or an IIS instance?

Comment: ya now it is working fine, can explain me what about this. Mr. Jeremy